# How can I pre define an array of structs

Tags: c

My c is very flakey and I'm not even 100% how to ask this question so please bear with me.

Basically what I'm attempting to do is to create a lookup table of structs of notes.

I know the structure I want and I have all the data that I want to put into it.

So how can I:

A) create an array of notes_type_t and fill it with all my data.

--- or  ---

B) Define a macro with all the data

--- or ---

C) a better way to do this

```
typedef struct 
{
   float freq;
   int   midi;
   char[2] note;


}notes_type_t


{
16.4, 12, C
17.3, 13, C#
18.4, 14, D
19.4, 15, D#
20.6, 16, E
21.8, 17, F
23.1, 18, F#
24.5, 19, G
26, 20, G#
27.5, 21, A
29.1, 22, A#
30.9, 23, B
32.7, 24, C
34.6, 25, C#
36.7, 26, D
38.9, 27, D#
41.2, 28, E
43.7, 29, F
46.2, 30, F#
49, 31, G
51.9, 32, G#
}
```

Comment: In what way would you like it to be better than method C?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, I was under the impression that the OP wanted a better method, not that he needed the syntax corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following possibly.  Suppose it is in `notes.h`:

```
typedef struct
{
   float freq;
   int   midi;
   char note[3];
}notes_type_t;

#if defined( DEFINE_NOTES )    
  notes_type_t notes[] = {
     {16.4, 12, "C"},
     {17.3, 13, "D#"},
     ...
     };
#else
  extern notes_type_t notes[];
#endif
```

Then in one source file, include notes.h with the `#define` as shown to actually define the array.  Other source files would just have the `#include` and get the `extern` declaration of the array.

```
#define DEFINE_NOTES
#include "notes.h"
```

Notice that the `note` element needs to be 3 characters (to allow room for the null terminator).

Comment: thanks for that. exactly what I need. Any idea how this could be defined as a macro so that I could just have it in a notes.h file.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what type of macro you are looking for.  But you can put the structure definition and the array declaration in a notes.h.  But you need to make sure you only define the array once.  I'll edit the answer to show one way of doing that.

Comment: thats brilliant. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
notes_type_t arr[] = {
  {16.4, 12, "C"},
  {17.3, 13, "C#"},
  {18.4, 14, "D"},
  {19.4, 15, "D#"},
  {20.6, 16, "E"},
  {21.8, 17, "F"},
  {23.1, 18, "F#"},
  {24.5, 19, "G"},
  {26, 20, "G#"},
  {27.5, 21, "A"},
  {29.1, 22, "A#"},
  {30.9, 23, "B"},
  {32.7, 24, "C"},
  {34.6, 25, "C#"},
  {36.7, 26, "D"},
  {38.9, 27, "D#"},
  {41.2, 28, "E"},
  {43.7, 29, "F"},
  {46.2, 30, "F#"},
  {49, 31, "G"},
  {51.9, 32, "G#"},
};
```

Note that your `note` field is too small. A C character is always `\0`-terminated and so always one larger than what you can see. Also it seems that your `note` field should have a variable length, so you might want to use a `const char*` instead.

It is also worth to consider the effect that large data fields (your example is not considered large) have on executable size etc. I'd rather read this information from a file, that's what you will have to do as soon as your program evolves anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of things wrong with your code.  Here's some working code that compiles and prints "C" and "C#".

```
typedef struct note
{
   float freq;
   int   midi;
   char  name[3];
} note;

note notes[] =
{
  {16.4, 12, "C"},
  {18.4, 14, "C#"},
  /** you can fill in the rest of the notes here **/
};

#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%s\n", notes[0].name);
  printf("%s\n", notes[1].name);
  return 0;
}
```

I changed the char array from "note" to "name" to avoid confusion.  Also I think you need it to be 3 long to hold the null termination character though I'm not sure.